# List of standard header files in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, header-files

Where could I find the list of all header files in C and C++?

While I am building a library, I am getting an error like '`tree.h not found`'.
I suppose this is a standard header file in C and C++.  This raised in me the curiosity to know all the header files and their contribution.

Is there a place I can search for?

I am working on Solaris Unix.

Comment: Are you asking about C, C++, or both?  There is no such language as C/C++, and asking about it is confusing (see below where you get an exhaustive list of C standard headers - is this useful for you?).

Comment: i am asking for both C and C++

Comment: You also care about the headers installed on your system

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/

However, you may also be refering to the header files of your OS. These can be found either on MSDN (Windows) or by `man` command (POSIX systems). Or another source if you're on another OS.

Answer (score 132):

The header 'tree.h' is not standard anywhere.

---

## C Standards

#### ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (C89, C90)

The 15 standard headers in C89 are:

```
<assert.h>  <limits.h>  <signal.h>  <stdlib.h>
<ctype.h>   <locale.h>  <stdarg.h>  <string.h>
<errno.h>   <math.h>    <stddef.h>  <time.h>
<float.h>   <setjmp.h>  <stdio.h>
```

#### ISO/IEC 9899:1990/Amd.1:1995

The 3 extra headers introduced in C94<sup>*</sup> (Amendment 1) are:

```
<iso646.h>  <wchar.h>  <wctype.h>
```

#### ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (C99)

The 6 extra headers in C99 are:

```
<complex.h>  <inttypes.h>  <stdint.h>  <tgmath.h>
<fenv.h>     <stdbool.h>
```

#### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (C11)

The 5 extra headers in C2011 (for a total of 29) are:

```
<stdalign.h>  <stdatomic.h>  <stdnoreturn.h>  <threads.h>  <uchar.h>
```

#### ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C17, C18)

No extra headers.

#### ISO/IEC 9899:2023 (C23)

The 2 extra headers in C2023 (for a total of 31) are:

```
<stdbit.h>  <stdckdint.h>
```

Some headers become obsolescent, notably:

```
<stdalign.h>  <stdbool.h>  <stdnoreturn.h>
```

---

#### ISO/IEC 9045:2008 (POSIX 2008, Single Unix Specification)

Note that [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) requires many more headers (82, including all the C99 headers).  The list below repeats the standard C (C99) headers.  Windows requires a different set of headers, of course.

```
<aio.h>        <libgen.h>       <spawn.h>         <sys/time.h>
<arpa/inet.h>  <limits.h>       <stdarg.h>        <sys/times.h>
<assert.h>     <locale.h>       <stdbool.h>       <sys/types.h>
<complex.h>    <math.h>         <stddef.h>        <sys/uio.h>
<cpio.h>       <monetary.h>     <stdint.h>        <sys/un.h>
<ctype.h>      <mqueue.h>       <stdio.h>         <sys/utsname.h>
<dirent.h>     <ndbm.h>         <stdlib.h>        <sys/wait.h>
<dlfcn.h>      <net/if.h>       <string.h>        <syslog.h>
<errno.h>      <netdb.h>        <strings.h>       <tar.h>
<fcntl.h>      <netinet/in.h>   <stropts.h>       <termios.h>
<fenv.h>       <netinet/tcp.h>  <sys/ipc.h>       <tgmath.h>
<float.h>      <nl_types.h>     <sys/mman.h>      <time.h>
<fmtmsg.h>     <poll.h>         <sys/msg.h>       <trace.h>
<fnmatch.h>    <pthread.h>      <sys/resource.h>  <ulimit.h>
<ftw.h>        <pwd.h>          <sys/select.h>    <unistd.h>
<glob.h>       <regex.h>        <sys/sem.h>       <utime.h>
<grp.h>        <sched.h>        <sys/shm.h>       <utmpx.h>
<iconv.h>      <search.h>       <sys/socket.h>    <wchar.h>
<inttypes.h>   <semaphore.h>    <sys/stat.h>      <wctype.h>
<iso646.h>     <setjmp.h>       <sys/statvfs.h>   <wordexp.h>
<langinfo.h>   <signal.h>
```

Note, too, that X/Open Curses requires another set of headers.  There was a new version (Release 7) of that specification released in November 2009 (the first update since 1996 — the primary differences are the loss of official support for termcap and pre-standard C `<varargs.h>` header).

```
<curses.h>  <term.h>  <uncntrl.h>
```

#### Linux Standards Base

There are other headers that you might need to use.  For example, there is no mention of `<getopt.h>` in these lists, but if you are using GNU Getopt (for long options, for example), you will need and use that header.  It is standard on Linux according to the [LSB, Linux Standards Base](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb).  An older version of the LSB was defined as ISO/IEC 23360:2006 in multiple parts; as of 2014-09-21, the current version of the LSB is 4.1 but version 5.0 is in beta.  There is a section of the document that defines which headers are included, but there is no convenient table of the headers in the version I looked at.  It is closely aligned with POSIX, but has extra facilities beyond what POSIX defines.

---

## C++ Standards

#### ISO/IEC 14882:1998 (C++98)

The standard lists 32 headers specific to C++:

```
<algorithm>   <iomanip>   <list>     <ostream>    <streambuf>
<bitset>      <ios>       <locale>   <queue>      <string>
<complex>     <iosfwd>    <map>      <set>        <typeinfo>
<deque>       <iostream>  <memory>   <sstream>    <utility>
<exception>   <istream>   <new>      <stack>      <valarray>
<fstream>     <iterator>  <numeric>  <stdexcept>  <vector>
<functional>  <limits>
```

There are also 18 headers corresponding to headers from C (corresponding to C94):

```
<cassert>  <ciso646>  <csetjmp>  <cstdio>   <ctime>
<cctype>   <climits>  <csignal>  <cstdlib>  <cwchar>
<cerrno>   <clocale>  <cstdarg>  <cstring>  <cwctype>
<cfloat>   <cmath>    <cstddef>
```

Intriguingly, Annex D (§D.7) lists a deprecated header, `<strstream>`, that is not mentioned earlier in the standard.  Including that header with GCC (`g++`) 7.2.0 generates a warning:

```
/opt/gcc/v7.2.0/include/c++/7.2.0/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2:
warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated
header which may be removed without further notice at a future date.
Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality
instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult
the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated. [-Wcpp]
```

The header `<strstream>` is explicitly listed in the other versions of the standard.

#### ISO/IEC 14882:2011 (C++11)

The 53 C++ headers in C++11 are:

```
<algorithm>           <initializer_list>  <numeric>           <system_error>
<array>               <iomanip>           <ostream>           <thread>
<atomic>              <ios>               <queue>             <tuple>
<bitset>              <iosfwd>            <random>            <type_traits>
<chrono>              <iostream>          <ratio>             <typeindex>
<codecvt>             <istream>           <regex>             <typeinfo>
<complex>             <iterator>          <scoped_allocator>  <unordered_map>
<condition_variable>  <limits>            <set>               <unordered_set>
<deque>               <list>              <sstream>           <utility>
<exception>           <locale>            <stack>             <valarray>
<forward_list>        <map>               <stdexcept>         <vector>
<fstream>             <memory>            <streambuf>
<functional>          <mutex>             <string>
<future>              <new>               <strstream>
```

The 26 headers related to C (C11) are:

```
<cassert>   <cinttypes>  <csignal>    <cstdio>   <cwchar>
<ccomplex>  <ciso646>    <cstdalign>  <cstdlib>  <cwctype>
<cctype>    <climits>    <cstdarg>    <cstring>
<cerrno>    <clocale>    <cstdbool>   <ctgmath>
<cfenv>     <cmath>      <cstddef>    <ctime>
<cfloat>    <csetjmp>    <cstdint>    <cuchar>
```

#### ISO/IEC 14882:2014 (C++14)

*Provisional list of headers based on draft standard N3797 found at [ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG21](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) site.  The data is from tables 14 and 15 in section 17.6.1.2 **Headers**, amended as noted below.  Since the standard has not been published (as of 2014-09-21), this list is not yet definitive.*

The 54 C++ headers in C++14 are:

```
<algorithm>           <initializer_list>  <numeric>           <strstream>
<array>               <iomanip>           <ostream>           <system_error>
<atomic>              <ios>               <queue>             <thread>
<bitset>              <iosfwd>            <random>            <tuple>
<chrono>              <iostream>          <ratio>             <type_traits>
<codecvt>             <istream>           <regex>             <typeindex>
<complex>             <iterator>          <scoped_allocator>  <typeinfo>
<condition_variable>  <limits>            <set>               <unordered_map>
<deque>               <list>              <shared_mutex>      <unordered_set>
<exception>           <locale>            <sstream>           <utility>
<forward_list>        <map>               <stack>             <valarray>
<fstream>             <memory>            <stdexcept>         <vector>
<functional>          <mutex>             <streambuf>
<future>              <new>               <string>
```

The 26 headers related to C (C11) are unchanged compared with C++11:

```
<cassert>   <cinttypes>  <csignal>    <cstdio>   <cwchar>
<ccomplex>  <ciso646>    <cstdalign>  <cstdlib>  <cwctype>
<cctype>    <climits>    <cstdarg>    <cstring>
<cerrno>    <clocale>    <cstdbool>   <ctgmath>
<cfenv>     <cmath>      <cstddef>    <ctime>
<cfloat>    <csetjmp>    <cstdint>    <cuchar>
```

There is one new header listed for C++14 compared to C++11, namely `<shared_mutex>`.

*NB: The draft lists a number of the headers (`<deque>`, `<istream>`, `<stdexcept>`, `<unordered_set>`) twice.  Also, 5 headers from C++11 are not listed in the tables in the draft, namely `<exception>`, `<iterator>`, `<ratio>`, `<scoped_allocator>`, and `<thread>`.  Since §18.8 defines `<exception>`, §24 defines `<iterator>`, §20.11 defines `<ratio>`, §30 defines `<thread>`, and §30.4 defines `<shared_mutex>`, this is an example of why you should not trust the draft standards as being the final word — they contain errors.*

#### ISO/IEC 14882:2017 (C++17)

*Provisional list of headers in C++17 based on the draft [N4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) dated 2017-03-21. This is a transcription of tables 16 and 17 from section 20.5.1.2 **Headers**.  This is not the final standard; in theory, something could change.*

There are 61 C++ headers:

```
<algorithm>           <future>            <numeric>           <strstream>
<any>                 <initializer_list>  <optional>          <system_error>
<array>               <iomanip>           <ostream>           <thread>
<atomic>              <ios>               <queue>             <tuple>
<bitset>              <iosfwd>            <random>            <type_traits>
<chrono>              <iostream>          <ratio>             <typeindex>
<codecvt>             <istream>           <regex>             <typeinfo>
<complex>             <iterator>          <scoped_allocator>  <unordered_map>
<condition_variable>  <limits>            <set>               <unordered_set>
<deque>               <list>              <shared_mutex>      <utility>
<exception>           <locale>            <sstream>           <valarray>
<execution>           <map>               <stack>             <variant>
<filesystem>          <memory>            <stdexcept>         <vector>
<forward_list>        <memory_resource>   <streambuf>
<fstream>             <mutex>             <string>
<functional>          <new>               <string_view>
```

The new headers compared to C++14 seem to be: `<any>`, `<execution>`, `<filesystem>`, `<memory_resource>`, `<optional>`, `<string_view>`, `<variant>`.

Again, the 26 headers related to C (C11) are unchanged compared with C++11 and C++14:

```
<cassert>   <cinttypes>  <csignal>    <cstdio>   <cwchar>
<ccomplex>  <ciso646>    <cstdalign>  <cstdlib>  <cwctype>
<cctype>    <climits>    <cstdarg>    <cstring>
<cerrno>    <clocale>    <cstdbool>   <ctgmath>
<cfenv>     <cmath>      <cstddef>    <ctime>
<cfloat>    <csetjmp>    <cstdint>    <cuchar>
```

See also [What are the new features in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17)

Note that some of the 'C library' headers are [deprecated](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html) in C++17, specifically `<ccomplex>`, `<cstdalign>`, `<cstdbool>`, `<ctgmath>` (and not `<ciso646>`).  The C++ header `<codecvt>` (added in C++11) is also deprecated in C++17.

#### ISO/IEC 14882:2020 (C++20)

*Provisional list of headers in C++17 based on the draft [N4878](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4878.pdf) dated 2020-12-15. This is a transcription of tables 23 and 24 from section 16.4.2.3 **Headers**.  This is not the final standard; in theory, something could change.*

There are 78 C++ headers:

```
<algorithm>           <forward_list>      <numbers>           <stop_token>
<any>                 <fstream>           <numeric>           <streambuf>
<array>               <functional>        <optional>          <string>
<atomic>              <future>            <ostream>           <string_view>
<barrier>             <initializer_list>  <queue>             <strstream>
<bit>                 <iomanip>           <random>            <syncstream>
<bitset>              <ios>               <ranges>            <system_error>
<charconv>            <iosfwd>            <ratio>             <thread>
<chrono>              <iostream>          <regex>             <tuple>
<codecvt>             <istream>           <scoped_allocator>  <typeindex>
<compare>             <iterator>          <semaphore>         <typeinfo>
<complex>             <latch>             <set>               <type_traits>
<concepts>            <limits>            <shared_mutex>      <unordered_map>
<condition_variable>  <list>              <source_location>   <unordered_set>
<coroutine>           <locale>            <span>              <utility>
<deque>               <map>               <sstream>           <valarray>
<exception>           <memory>            <stack>             <variant>
<execution>           <memory_resource>   <stacktrace>        <vector>
<filesystem>          <mutex>             <stdexcept>         <version>
<format>              <new>
```

The new headers compared to C++17 are: `<barrier>`, `<bit>`, `<charconv>`, `<compare>`, `<concepts>`, `<coroutine>`, `<format>`, `<latch>`, `<numbers>`, `<ranges>`, `<semaphore>`, `<source_location>`, `<span>`, `<stacktrace>`, `<stop_token>`, `<syncstream>`, `<version>`.

There are only 21 C compatibility headers in C++20 (compared with 26 in C++17).  These are:

```
<cassert>  <cfenv>      <climits>  <csetjmp>  <cstddef>  <cstdlib>  <cuchar>
<cctype>   <cfloat>     <clocale>  <csignal>  <cstdint>  <cstring>  <cwchar>
<cerrno>   <cinttypes>  <cmath>    <cstdarg>  <cstdio>   <ctime>    <cwctype>
```

The omitted headers compared with C++17 are: `<ccomplex>`, `<ciso646>`, `<cstdalign>`, `<cstdbool>`, `<ctgmath>`.

#### ISO/IEC 14882:2023 (C++23)

*Provisional list of headers in C++23 based on the draft [N4928](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/n4928.pdf) dated 2022-12-18. This is a transcription of tables 25 and 26 from section 16.4.2.3 **Headers**.  This is not the final standard; in theory, something could change.*

There are 86 C++ headers:

```
<algorithm>           <format>            <new>               <stdexcept>
<any>                 <forward_list>      <numbers>           <stdfloat>
<array>               <fstream>           <numeric>           <stop_token>
<atomic>              <functional>        <optional>          <streambuf>
<barrier>             <future>            <ostream>           <string>
<bit>                 <generator>         <print>             <string_view>
<bitset>              <initializer_list>  <queue>             <strstream>
<charconv>            <iomanip>           <random>            <syncstream>
<chrono>              <ios>               <ranges>            <system_error>
<codecvt>             <iosfwd>            <ratio>             <thread>
<compare>             <iostream>          <regex>             <tuple>
<complex>             <istream>           <scoped_allocator>  <type_traits>
<concepts>            <iterator>          <semaphore>         <typeindex>
<condition_variable>  <latch>             <set>               <typeinfo>
<coroutine>           <limits>            <shared_mutex>      <unordered_map>
<deque>               <list>              <source_location>   <unordered_set>
<exception>           <locale>            <span>              <utility>
<execution>           <map>               <spanstream>        <valarray>
<expected>            <mdspan>            <sstream>           <variant>
<filesystem>          <memory>            <stack>             <vector>
<flat_map>            <memory_resource>   <stacktrace>        <version>
<flat_set>            <mutex>
```

The 8 new headers compared to C++20 are: `<expected>`, `<flat_map>`, `<flat_set>`, `<generator>`, `<mdspan>`, `<print>`, `<spanstream>`, `<stdfloat>`.

The 21 C headers listed in C++23 are the same as in C++20:

```
<cassert>  <cfenv>      <climits>  <csetjmp>  <cstddef>  <cstdlib>  <cuchar>
<cctype>   <cfloat>     <clocale>  <csignal>  <cstdint>  <cstring>  <cwchar>
<cerrno>   <cinttypes>  <cmath>    <cstdarg>  <cstdio>   <ctime>    <cwctype>
```

---

<sup>*</sup> *The 'off by one year' issues in the dates are due to the time it takes to process the standard after it is approved.  ANSI approved the original C standard in [1989](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C); ISO approved it in 1990.  Amendment 1 was approved in 1994; it was released in 1995. Similar comments apply to C17/C18 and may well end up applying to C23/C24.*

Answer (score 8):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ lists all the standard C++ headers and the C++ wrappers of C header files.

tree.h is not part of the standard library.

Answer (score 6):

I found this [Wikipedia entry on the C standard library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) which contains, lists of C header files and detailed information on *which* standard they're part of. That gives you a nice historical perspective and some other, similar details.

Of course that's just C. There's a similar article to be found under "C++ standard library". That also has references to some other libraries which may not be "standard" per se but without which C++ would feel "crippled" to some people used to working with the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

This contains all the header's that you can use in c++ language
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It would be helpful if you identified which system(s) provide this header — or the system where you found it — because it is not standardized and won't be available on many systems.  That limits its usefulness.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).