# error: expected ')' before '*' token

Tags: c

I have this include file (`memory .h`)

```
#ifndef MEMORY_H
#define MEMORY_H

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef struct mmemory {
        int* cells;
        int* current_cell;
        int cells_number;
    } memory;

    void memory_init(memory* mymemory, int size);
    void step_left(memory* mymemory, int steps);
    void step_right(memory* mymemory, int steps);
    void cell_inc(memory* mymemory, int quantity);
    void print_cell(memory* mymemory);
    void get_char(memory* mymemory);


#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* MEMORY_H */
```

And this implementation file (`memory.c`)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "memory.h"

void
memory_init (memory* mymemory, int size)
{
    mymemory->cells = (int*) malloc (sizeof (int) * size);
    mymemory->cells_number = size;
    mymemory->current_cell = (int*) ((mymemory->cells_number / 2) * sizeof (int));
}
... //other function definitions follow
```

When I try to compile `memory.c` I get this error for each and every function definition

> src/memory.c:5: error: expected ')' before '*' token

where line 5 is the function definition for `memory_init()`

Can someone please tell me why I'm getting this error?

Comment: gcc version 4.2.1 on OSX Snow Leopard, with -ansi switch

Comment: Maybe some  other Header already defined MEMORY_H before your header is included?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because the system `memory.h` is shadowing your `memory.h`, causing the `#include` to succeed without declaring your types.  Several possible fixes:

- Rename your file -- probably for the best in any case, to reduce potential confusion.
- Include your file via a prefix subdirectory (e.g., `#include <myproj/memory.h>`).
- Move your file into the same directory as the source file, allowing the `#include` precedence rules for filenames wrapped in `"` to take effect.
- Ensure that your C pre-processor include path options place your project header path prior to the system header paths.

Comment: To avoid future problems, is there a quick reference for standard C header names?

Comment: @klez That appears to be an existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027991/list-of-standard-header-files-in-c-and-c .  In this case though, the standards-related lists wouldn't have helped, because `memory.h` isn't a standard header.  You can always see what your particular OS provides with something like `find /usr/include/ -type f -name '*.h'`.

Comment: Provided, of course, that your particular OS has `find`, and keeps headers in `/usr/include/`.  Not all people are lucky enough to run such OSes.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is really late, but I encountered a similar problem.

I think your problem is related to a typo in your **.h** file where you declare a struct **mm**emory. If you remove that extra 'm' it should work.

Comment: Your answer is really late and the problem wasn't that :-) Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

In your code you have defined like this for memory.h

```
#ifndef MEMORY_H
#define MEMORY_H
...
...
#endif
```

In case any of your other files which you use in your project is having the same #define i.e MEMORY_H then you can get this error.

Solution:

```
#ifndef XYZ_MEMORY_H
#define XYZ_MEMORY_H
...
...
#endif
```