# Learning to use GCC

Tags: c, gcc, header-files

I am a student of computer science and for reasons beyond my comprehension i have only been taught to code in the TURBO compiler.

But now i have realized that i should learn to code in GCC. The problem is that i dont know any of the header files and therefore i am not able to use any of the built in functions.

All the GCC tutorials i have seen are for beginners. I am at more of an intermediate state of learning and hence if any of you know of a book or a website where i can learn the details about the header files then it would be helpful.

NOTE: just to be clear-i am a linux user.

Comment: You dont code in GCC. You compile with GCC. Header files have nothing to do with GCC they are language specific.

Comment: I get the impression that Turbo C is very popular in CS courses in India.  Pretty much all the questions about it here on Stack Overflow come from students at Indian universities.

Comment: @webclectic: Alas, not so simple.  Turbo C is massively outdated, so its support of the C++ standard and the standard library is significantly impaired.

Comment: @webclectic: okay. I want to compile a C program using GCC. So i need to know the header files. For eg: TURBOC has a header file called time.h which contains functions dealing with timing your code. How do i find an equivalent here?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth :yes. :) it is favoured to the exclusion of all other C compilers and as you said it is massively outdated.

Comment: @ChaitanyaNettem: Your reasoning is flawed, though: You need to know the haader files if you want to **learn C**, not because you want to use the GCC compiler. The distinction is crucial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conio.h is not the standard header file it is available only in turbo c compiler

Check out these links

http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/index.html

http://www.di-mgt.com.au/src/CStdLib.html

and the previous stackoverflow question [List of standard header files in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027991/list-of-standard-header-files-in-c-and-c)

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/

http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library

http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/

http://www.utas.edu.au/infosys/info/documentation/C/CStdLib.html

Answer (score 0):

Most of the header files used by gcc are either C C++ or POSIX compliant. Therefore you need to learn the language. printf is in stdio.h in every C compiler that is standards compliant.

There are specific linux ones but you probably dont care about those. If you ware using a linux system the 'man' command is your friend - but it tells you the header file.

```
 man 3 printf
```

produces

```
NAME
   printf, fprintf, sprintf, snprintf, vprintf, vfprintf, vsprintf, vsnprintf - formatted output conversion

 SYNOPSIS
   #include <stdio.h>
 ....
```

Comment: But there are differences. To create text user interfaces and to control them you have to use the conio.h header file in Turbo. 

Whereas i am told the same is done using ncurses in gcc. So how do i learn about these differences?

Answer (score 0):

Like if you want to use printf() (for eg..), just type `man printf` (man stands for manual) in your terminal if Linux or in google and you'l get all the thing you need to use printf:

```
Synopsis

#include <stdio.h>
int printf (const char *format, ...); 
int fprintf (FILE *stream, const char *format, ...); 
int sprintf (char *str, const char *format, ...); 
int snprintf (char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);

#include <stdarg.h>

int vprintf (const char *format, va_list ap); 
int vfprintf (FILE *stream, const char *format, va_list ap); 
int vsprintf (char *str, const char *format, va_list ap); 
int vsnprintf (char *str, size_t size, const char *format, va_list ap);
```

Then to use printf(), you see that you need to include stdio.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Normally you can compile without including it but it gives you warning..

Moreover use <> to include standart header files and "" to include your headers like: `#include "myHeaderinMyLocalFolder.h"`

Answer (score 0):

If TURBO-C (which I guess you meant) is anything like TURBO-PASCAL, with it's library of console functions, there is nothing like that in standard C. And standard C is what is usedby gcc, so if you know how to use the functions in e.g. `stdio.h` then there is not much difference.