# Is there one include file that covers all file operations?

Tags: c, linux-mint

OK, maybe not, but which ones do you need in order read, write and delete files and directories? I've got stdio.h and stat.h and now I find I need unistd.h in order to use unlink. I've never heard of unistd.h. Maybe I should be using something else besides unlink?
Right now I'm using C on Linux Mint.

Comment: `stdio.h` provides `remove()` for deleting a file

Comment: You can use `remove()` instead of `unlink()`; it's in `<stdio.h>`.  It will remove empty directories. `<unistd.h>` is the primary POSIX header. It has `mkdir()` and `rmdir()`. There are a myriad others you might need, depending on what you're up to (`<dirent.h>`, `<ftw.h>`, `<aio.h>`, …).  See [List of standard header files in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027991/) for a list of possible headers.  (Note that the standard header for `stat()` is `<sys/stat.h>`, not `<stat.h>`.  And, somewhat tangentially, `<time.h>` and `<sys/time.h>` define separate sets of facilities.)

Comment: Thanks guys, er, peoples. The program reads directories, so I used POSIX calls. Seemed like a good idea at the time. Could have sworn that I ran it on Linux, but it's beginning to look like that never happened.