# Edit char array in C, output cut off

Tags: arrays, c, strcpy, strcat

First of all, I know that there are a lot of questions about this topic. But I have searched a lot and tested the solutions I found with similar issues but without success.

I want to edit a char array when foo is called and another when bar is called, but the output keeps getting cut off (see below).

main.c

```
#include "struct.h"

static bool on = true;
static long val = 1;
static char first[15];
static char value[13];
static char second[15];

void foo(void)
{
    strcpy(first, (char*)hello); // first = "Hello "
    LongToStr(val, value);       // value = "1"
    Ltrim(value);
    Rtrim(value);
    strcat(first, value);        // first = "Hello 1"
    strcat(first, (char*)world); // first = "Hello 1 world"

    set(0, first);
}

void bar(void)
{
    on =! on;

    strcpy(second, (char*)fooBar);      // second = "fooBar "

    if (on)
        strcat(second, (char*)OnText);  // second = "fooBar on"
    else
        strcat(second, (char*)OffText); // second = "fooBar off"

    set(1, second);
}

int main()
{
    init();

    foo();
    printf("%s", get(0));

    foo();
    printf("%s", get(0));

    bar();
    printf("%s", get(1));

    bar();
    printf("%s", get(1));
}
```

struct.c

```
#include "struct.h"

static myStruct a[2];

void init(void)
{
    a[0].b = hello;
    a[1].b = fooBar;
}

void set(short pos, char* new)
{
    a[pos].b = new;
}

const char* get(short pos)
{
    return a[pos].b;
}
```

struct.h

```
void init(void);
void set(short pos, char* new);
const char* get(short pos);

typedef struct {
    const char *b;
} myStruct;

static const char hello[] = "Hello ";
static const char world[] = " world";
static const char fooBar[] = "fooBar ";
static const char OnText[] = "on";
static const char OffText[] = "off";
```

**Output:**

```
1
1
on
```

Seriously, what am I missing here?

**Edit:**
Documentation of mikroC built-in functions:
[strcpy](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/compilers/mikroc/pic/help/ansi_string_library.htm#strcpy)
[Ltrim](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/compilers/mikroc/pic/help/conversions_library.htm#ltrim)
[Rtrim](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/compilers/mikroc/pic/help/conversions_library.htm#rtrim)
[LongToStr](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/compilers/mikroc/pic/help/conversions_library.htm#longtostr)
[strcat](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/compilers/mikroc/pic/help/ansi_string_library.htm#strcat)

Comment: Note that using the header `"string.h"` is likely to cause confusion with the standard header `<string.h>` — do not create your own header with the same name as a standard header.  Learn and avoid creating standard header names.  See [List of standard headers in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2027991/15168).

Comment: `static myStruct a[1];` is an array of size 1. `a[1].b = fooBar;` is undefined behavior.  All other questions are moot.

Comment: You could have it in one source file for us.  What magic functions Ltrim Ltrim, LongToStr do?

Comment: `static myStruct a[1];` => `static myStruct a[2];` you access **two** elements not one!!

Comment: And, never use `gets`.  Even if merely as a word in the title of the question! :)

Comment: The casts in `strcpy(first, (char*)hello);` and `strcpy(first, (char*)world);` are undesirable.  They're unnecessary too — `strcpy()` takes a `const char * restrict` as the second argument, so the cast isn't needed.  And it makes the code more verbose.  Casts are useful in the correct places — but you should avoid using them as much as possible.

Comment: Does this actually compile? I see no declaration of `a` that is reachable from `main`.

Comment: @jonathan sorry, updated the question. Copied some parts of the code without thinking it through. Also added links to documentation of the built-in functions.

Comment: Please post the **exact** output you are getting, and the **exact** output you are expecting to get. Not your interpretations, just the characters that appear on the standard output.

Comment: Have you read the documentation you link? LongToStr: *Requires: Destination string should be at least 12 characters in length*.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. the comments show the expected output, "**Output:**" at the bottom of my question show the actual output. Yes I have read it, but missed a 1 in the code I posted here, fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by not declaring the char arrays as constants (but not sure why).

```
static char hello[] = "Hello ";
static char world[] = " world";
static char fooBar[] = "fooBar ";
static char OnText[] = "on";
static char OffText[] = "off";
```